# Convert Rows to Column having Repeating Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Current Table mentioned below:

```
ActivityName            Username ProcessingTime WaitingTime
----------------------- -------- -------------- -----------
Branch_Maker            nikhil                6          10
Branch_Checker          nikhil                0          69
Director                nikhil                3          57
Branch_Checker          nikhil               32          64
Branch_Checker          nikhil               12          23
```

I need to display the ProcessingTime and Waiting Time for each ActivityName as a column, something like below

```
Username Branch_Maker Processing Time    Branch_MakerWaitingTime    Branch_Checker ProcessingTime   Branch_Checker Waiting    Director ProcessingTime     Director WaitingTime
-------- ----------------------------    -----------------------     ---------------------------     -----------------------  --------------------------  -------------------
nikhil           6                       10                                        0                    69                         3                       57
nikhil                                                                            32                    64                                                
nikhil                                                                            12                    23
```

I have tried query as below

```
SELECT 
    ProcessInstanceId, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Branch_Maker' THEN ProcessingTime END) AS Branch_Maker_ProcessingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Branch_Maker' THEN WaitingTime END) AS Branch_Maker_WaitingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Branch_Checker' THEN ProcessingTime END) AS Branch_Checker_ProcessingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Branch_Checker' THEN WaitingTime END) AS Branch_Checker_WaitingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Director' THEN ProcessingTime END) AS Director_ProcessingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Director' THEN WaitingTime END) AS Director_WaitingTime
FROM 
    abc_test_1
GROUP BY 
    ProcessInstanceId;
```

Its returning below

```
ProcessInstanceId      Branch_Maker_ProcessingTime Branch_Maker_WaitingTime Branch_Checker_ProcessingTime Branch_Checker_WaitingTime Director_ProcessingTime Director_WaitingTime
---------------------- --------------------------- ------------------------ ----------------------------- -------------------------- ----------------------- --------------------
COB-0000024750-process                           6                       10                             0                         69                       3                   57
```

Comment: Please show is what you have tried.

Comment: @DaleK, I have updated my question with what I have done.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/luVZ15n-

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal, its not showing all the result of Branch_Checker, its just showing the max value which I already tried.

Comment: Add a row number per attribute name and then group by row number also. https://dbfiddle.uk/sXSdgGiN

Comment: @astentx Your fiddle displays the answer, so why not provide as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell because it almost always turns out that there are additional requirements such as specific distribution order, additional grouping etc, when such one-liner becomes either innacurate or incomplete. Unfortunately, I didn't have much time to write thoroughly explained answer (that is my internal requirement) for this particular question (which seems to be abandoned at all).

Answer (score 0):

You outline your requirements that include:

1. Two columns (processing time & wait time) per ActivityName (there are 3 of these) so a total of 6 pivoted data columns
2. plus, a row for the maximum number of measurments within single ActivityName. The ActivityName "Branch_Checker" has the most measurments (3) so we require 3 rows.

The table below summarises the desired output (nb the headings are abbreviated), but it includes a column that shows how we might meet the second requirement - by assigning a number to each of measurments within an ActivityName:

| User | #_measures | BM_ProcTime | BM_WaitTime | BC_ProcTime | BC_WaitTime | D_ProcTime | D_WaitTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nikhil | 1 | 6 | 10 | 0 | 69 | 3 | 57 |
| nikhil | 2 | *null* | *null* | 32 | 64 | *null* | *null* |
| nikhil | 3 | *null* | *null* | 12 | 23 | *null* | *null* |

So, there needs to be a method for numbering the measurements introduced into the query so that the wanted rows are provided. This can be achieved by using a "window function" `row_number()` together with an `over()` clause. Within the over clause we can `partition by username, activityname` - which resets the row_number to 1 for each new partition, then we can `order by` any column or columns which wil control the sequence of assigned row numbers. It isn't stated how the row order should be controlled and as there are very few columns to choose from so, here we simply choose actvityname. The suggested query is:

```
-- without showing the row number (as required)
with prep as (
  select
    *
    , row_number() over(partition by Username, ActivityName
                        order by ActivityName )
      as no_of_measures
  from abc_test_1
)
SELECT 
    Username,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Branch_Maker' THEN ProcessingTime END) AS BM_ProcessingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Branch_Maker' THEN WaitingTime END) AS BM_WaitingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Branch_Checker' THEN ProcessingTime END) AS BC_ProcessingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Branch_Checker' THEN WaitingTime END) AS BC_WaitingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Director' THEN ProcessingTime END) AS D_ProcessingTime, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityName = 'Director' THEN WaitingTime END) AS D_WaitingTime
FROM 
    prep
GROUP BY 
    Username, no_of_measures;
```

which produces:

| Username | BM_ProcTime | BM_WaitTime | BC_ProcTime | BC_WaitTime | D_ProcTime | D_WaitTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nikhil | 6 | 10 | 0 | 69 | 3 | 57 |
| nikhil | *null* | *null* | 32 | 64 | *null* | *null* |
| nikhil | *null* | *null* | 12 | 23 | *null* | *null* |

[see it working here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BblQubKZ)

**NB** the origin of this answer was by **@astentx** in a comment beneath the question.